# Return Point for printing, inherritance used

Tags: c++, pointers, printing, constants, operator-keyword

- THIS ORIGINAL PROBLEM IS SOLVED, IN THE COMMENT IS THE PROBLEM THAT OCCURRED LATER;

  > How can I make Layer::printInfo() to print the info using the GeoObject::printInfo() ?

About the structure: Marker is inherrited from class GeoObject. In GeoObject the file Point.h is included. The information stored in the class Point are int longt and int lat (longtitude, latitude of the coordinate Point).

Now I am trying to print the information stored in an object of class Marker by overwriting the virtual method printInfo (which is inherrited from GeoObject). The problem is in this line:
`str << GeoObject::getDesc() << ": " << GeoObject::getPoint().Print() << ", " << size << ", "<< colour ;`

I get `error: no matching function to call to 'Point::Print()'`
From this I conclude that the GeoObject::getPoint does return an object of type Point and I do not understand why I am not able to print the coordinate.

Below are the important parts of code (I spared you all the codes that are irrelevant for this problem)

(Marker.cpp)

```
string Marker::printInfo() const {
    ostringstream str ; // used like ostream out
    // get the description given to the GeoObject stored in this Marker
    str << GeoObject::getDesc() << ": " << GeoObject::getPoint().Print() << ", " << size << ", "<< colour ;
    return str.str() ; // take stringversion of string }
```

(GeoObject.h)

```
Point getPoint() const
        {
            return coordinate ;
        }
```

(Point.cpp)

```
void Print(ostream &out)
        {
            out << longt <<", "<<lat ;
        }
```

Comment: `Print()` expects 1 argument.

Comment: The problem above is solved, but somehow still nothing is printed. Pointers to different objects of class GeoObject (inherrited classes are Marker and Polygon) are stored in list<GeoObject*> myLayer. The method GeoObject::printInfo() is called in the method Layer::printInfo() to print all data of the layer. The code below (**see next comment**) is used. In the output I see that Layer::printInfo() is called, but no information is printed. Why? **How can I print that information?**

Comment: void Layer::printInfo() const
{
    // using for every stored GeoObject the printInfo method that is written for it.
    for(list<GeoObject*>::const_iterator it = myLayer.begin() ;
        it != myLayer.end() ; it ++ )
        {
            cout << (*it)->printInfo() ; // printInfo returns a string
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

`Print` takes an `ostream` as a parameter.

```
void Print(ostream &out)
```

Change this line:

```
str << GeoObject::getDesc() << ": " << GeoObject::getPoint().Print() << ", " << size << ", "<< colour ;
```

To this:

```
str << GeoObject::getDesc() << ": ";
GeoObject::getPoint().Print(str);
str << ", " << size << ", "<< colour ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick, on to solving the other errors. ;-)